# How to cite this article composed of sections, each written by different authors?

Tags: citation-style

I have a question about citing [this article](https://www.oxfordartonline.com/view/10.1093/gao/9781884446054.001.0001/oao-9781884446054-e-7000073405#oao-9781884446054-e-7000073405-div1-7000073423). In case you cannot access it, it is composed of different sections, each written by a different author. I would like to refer to one of the sections in Harvard style, but how do I do that? Do I do this?

> Last Name, Initials. (Year) Name of section, in (list all the authors), Name of article,
> Grove Art Online. Link

Or this?

> Last Name, Initials. (Year) Name of section, in Name of article, Grove Art Online. Link

Comment: what is the function of your writing?

Comment: An undergraduate essay.

Answer (score -1):

Function of OP's writing is "undergraduate essay" which I assume means that the grading criteria don't include correct referencing.

In that case there are two approaches:

1. most likely any way you cite/reference is OK. Nobody will likely check the quote, and if you quote directly then they will be able to find it using text search
2. when in doubt ask your instructor or TA, as the are the sole determiners of what is "correct". When you will submit that essay to an editor for publication - ask the editor. When you submit it as part of thesis - ask thesis committee.

Comment: As it happens, I am penalized for incorrect referencing, so the first part of your answer (that I can cite any way I want) is not helpful. Also, there are standard referencing formats (in science, the typical one used is APA), so my instructor is not the sole determiner for what is OK. Anyway, I asked my university's librarian, and they told me to use option 2.